# Select where MAX(DATE) between X and X

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to select only patients, who had their LAST appointment in the year 2015. The ideal thing would look like this:

```
Select person.name, person.surname
inner join patient on patient.pat_id=person.per_id
inner join appointment on appointment.pat_id=patient.pat_id
where MAX(appointment.date) between '31.12.2014'and '01.01.2016'
```

But of MAX isn't allowed in WHERE clause. What's the best workaround?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close:

```
Select p.name, p.surname
from person p inner join
     patient pa
     on pa.pat_id = p.per_id join
     appointment a
     on a.pat_id = pa.pat_id
group by p.per_id, p.name, p.surname
having max(a.date) >= date '2015-01-01' and
      max(a.date) < date '2016-01-01';
```

Notes:

- You need `group by`.
- Note that I'm including `per_id` in the `group by`, because different people can have the same name.
- Date constants can be introduced with the `date` keyword.
- Do not use `between` with dates; this is particularly true in Oracle where a `date` column can have a time component.

Comment: `Where` or `Having`?

Comment: i think you meant writing `HAVING` instead off `WHERE` here?

Comment: I see it now. It works with HAVING. Thank you @GordonLinoff !

Comment: Adding a unique `ID` in a `GROUP BY` *but not in the SELECT list* is IMO not the best advice. If the name is not unique, you can't interpret the result of the query.